# Howl Editor Setting a Shortcut Key

Tags: text-editor

How to configure the Howl text editor to quit at pressing Ctrl+X?
The command is already there, but one needs to Press Alt+X and then
'q' and Enter. Those are four keystrokes, I would like to reduce it to two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-X is set to editor-cut, but check the [Howl Faq](https://github.com/howl-editor/howl/wiki/Howl-FAQ#key-bindings). There is an example to set the exit command to Ctrl-Q to exit, so following that, it's probably this in the ~/.howl/init.moon file:

```
howl.bindings.push { ctrl_x: 'quit' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by pressing Alt+F4, which was the same key combo I have used on TextAdept. Anyway, it would be interesting to have some answers other than mine.

Comment: Alt+F4 is a key combination capture by the window manager, that sends the close event to the app, it is not a configured key in the editor.